# NTP project in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, ntp

I'm sort of making a Network Time Protocol (NTP) project in java and I'm asked to make at least 3 clients connect to a server and get time with fixed delay and stuff.

My question is how can i make a server to accept many clients... which is the simplest way? Can I do it with a single socket? or is it simpler to just do it with threads?

Answer (score 1):

Without using threads, you will block all other connections until your conversation is complete with one client. You will have to use multithreading. There are a number of great resources online [like this one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html).

Basically, you will loop and each time you `accept()` and create a new socket, you either create a new thread to deal with it, or hand it to a thread pool.

Comment: ok I'l use mutlithreading but can u show me what to do with the sockets?

Comment: If there's just a simple trick or something...

Comment: It is not extremely simple, but it takes just a little bit of thinking. Basically you have a ServerSocket that sits and listens for connections. When it gets one, you accept it, and that returns a Socket. Then you can write to them using a buffered writer/reader. Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: @user2375278 Follow the link provided in the answer. You won't be spoon-fed code examples on this site - we expect you to do your own research.

Comment: Ive done quite a research already on this project...
just coz I'm out of time... I was looking for a fast answer... :/

Comment: also the link provided just gives too much code and doesnt work...